# Producer for already provided RabbitMq via Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I find myself in an environment where the rabbitmq's are already provided as given infrastructure.

A *Service A* is writing into the rabbit queues and *Service B* is reading from the queues. The reading part as a *consumer* via *Spring Cloud Stream Binder* is working like a charme after intensive reading the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit) and setting it up properly.

However i am not able to set up a **producer** which is going to write into the rabbit queues.

---

**Setup**

RabbitMq (*already up and running*)

- 1 Exchange: myExchange
- 3 Queues: myQueueA, myQueueB, myQueueC (under **myExchange** linked)

Producer-Service (above mentioned **Service A**)

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding(RabbitChannelSource.class)
public class RabbitSender
{
    private final RabbitChannelSource rabbitChannelSource;


    public void sendMessage()
    {
        Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload("TEEEEST").build();
        rabbitChannelSource.myOutput().send(msg);
    }
```

```java
public interface RabbitChannelSource
{
    String MY_OUTPUT_BINDING = "my-output";

    @Output(MY_OUTPUT_BINDING)
    MessageChannel myOutput();

}
```

I am trying to make it work first for one queue, but ideally i would set the properties right for **all three** queues.

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=user
spring.rabbitmq.password=pass

## use existing rabbitmq via bindings
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-output.destination=my-output
#spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-output.group=myQueueA
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-output.producer.required-groups=myQueueA
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.my-output.producer.bind-queue=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.my-output.producer.declare-exchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.my-output.producer.queueNameGroupOnly=true
```

`bind-queue=false` and `declare-exchange=false` is necessary since i have rabbit infrastructure.

---

But however i am getting always the same exception, i could not figure out why. I mean i know why, because there is no appropriate channel istantiated to send messages to. So i am suspecting it has something to do with the `application.properties`.

```java
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.my-output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[7], headers={contentType=application/json, id=98698b4c-61fa-596d-736e-f630d3ba4626, timestamp=1605105272723}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.rabbitmq.RabbitSender.sendMessage(RabbitSender.java:25)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.event.TriggeredEmsImport.execute(TriggeredImport.java:95)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.event.TriggeredEmsImport$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d84f31a4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.event.TriggeredEmsImport$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a0878aed.execute(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:305)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:209)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:379)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:268)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.EmsReceiverApplication.main(EmsReceiverApplication.java:21)
```

I want to be able to write into `myQueueA, myQueueB or myQueueC` based on a routingKey. So if i set routingKey inside my application to `myQA` the message should be send to `myQueueA`, for `myQB` then to `myQueueB`, and for `myQC` then to `myQueueC`.

So three different routing keys lead to the corresponding rabbit queue.

I am happy to any input since i have tried many things which did not lead to me any success. Thank you!

Comment: What is `testSending()`? I see no such method.

Comment: It's `sendMessage()`, I just renamed it. Sorry my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are trying to use the binding before it is bound? This works fine for me:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=my-output
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.declare-exchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routeTo']
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class So64788954Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64788954Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    Source source;

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                    .setHeader("routeTo", "myQA")
                    .build());

            source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("bar")
                    .setHeader("routeTo", "myQB")
                    .build());

            source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("baz")
                    .setHeader("routeTo", "myQC")
                    .build());

        };
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = { "myQueueA", "myQueueB", "myQueueC" } )
    void listen(String in, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue) {
        System.out.println(in + ", from: " + queue);
    }

}
```

```
foo, from: myQueueA
bar, from: myQueueB
baz, from: myQueueC
```

You don't need required groups on the producer side when you bring your own queues/exchanges.

`The` @RabbitListener` is just there to consume the messages sent to the 3 queues.

By the way, the annotation model is deprecated; the functional programming model is now preferred, where we use a `StreamBridge` for output (and `Consumer<?>` or `Function<?, ?>` to consume and process respectively).

Here is the equivalent of the above:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.my-output.producer.declare-exchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.my-output.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routeTo']
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So64788954Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64788954Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    StreamBridge bridge;

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            bridge.send("my-output", MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                    .setHeader("routeTo", "myQA")
                    .build());

            bridge.send("my-output", MessageBuilder.withPayload("bar")
                    .setHeader("routeTo", "myQB")
                    .build());

            bridge.send("my-output", MessageBuilder.withPayload("baz")
                    .setHeader("routeTo", "myQC")
                    .build());

        };
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = { "myQueueA", "myQueueB", "myQueueC" } )
    void listen(String in, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue) {
        System.out.println(in + ", from: " + queue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thank your for your answer. I am not able to check your suggestion since another thing came up. As soon as i get to it, i'll give you an update!

Comment: I tried the first model, i am getting the same error as in my post.

For the new Model i get another arror, but while debugging it, i have no output linked to the `StreamBridge`. Am i completely missing out on something? So curious to find out ..

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[7], headers={routeTo=CRE, id=afb2a163-c110-96a8-0ee6-acc26a3d640b, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1606302368009}]`

For the first Suggestion.

Comment: If you can't figure out what's different to my example, post a small, complete, stripped-down example that exhibits this behavior, and I'll take a look; I can't help further without seeing real code/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After Gary's suggestion i get the same error as in my first post.

*application.properties*

```
# --- spring cloud ---
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=username
spring.rabbitmq.password=password
## use existing rabbitmq via bindings
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=my-output
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.declare-exchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.routing-key-expression=headers['routeTo']
```

*RabbitTrigger.java*

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RabbitTrigger
{
    private final RabbitSender rabbitSender;


    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void execute()
    {
        rabbitSender.testSending();
    }

}
```

*RabbitSender.java*

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class RabbitSender
{
    private final Source source;


    public void testSending()
    {
        Message<String> testMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload("TEEEEST")
                                                    .setHeader("routeTo", "CRE")
                                                    .build();
        source.output().send(testMessage);
    }
```

But i get the same exception as i was getting in my initial post. I assume i did not consider a crucial part to this?

```
2020-11-25 16:27:17,116 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[7], headers={routeTo=CRE, id=15479810-375f-38e8-a692-e84c6ede01d7, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1606318037108}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.rabbitmq.RabbitSender.testSending(RabbitSender.java:34)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.event.RabbitTrigger.execute(RabbitTrigger.java:96)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.event.RabbitTrigger$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d84f31a4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.event.RabbitTrigger$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d00eff49.execute(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:305)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:209)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:379)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:268)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at de.techem.emsreceiver.EmsReceiverApplication.main(EmsReceiverApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Setting up the producer is way more complicated for me than it was for the consumer part.